# jquery keyup function not working when a page is loaded using load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a jsp page say a.jsp on which i have a select box, on change of a select box i'm loading another jsp page say b.jsp. I'm loading b.jsp page to one div whose id is 'q_bank_criteria'. In a.jsp i have key up function for class assmt_count as below, which is not working, but when i directly include the content of b.jsp it worked. what may be the problem?

```
$('#assmt_count').keyup(function() {
 alert("hi");
});
```

--a.jsp--

```
$('select[name=final_assessment_id]').change(function () {
   $('#q_bank_criteria').load('b.jsp.jsp?assessment_id=' + assessment_id, function() {

   });
});
```

--b.jsp--

```
<div>                            
    <label>Select questions from assessment</label>
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id="th1">Complexity type</th>
                <th id="th2">Total Questions</th>
                <th id="th4">Enter no's to display</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <%
                String assessment_id = request.getParameter("assessment_id").trim();
                String sqla1 = "SELECT c.complexity_type_id,c.complexity_type_name, COUNT( qb.question_id ) as cnt "
                        + "FROM assessment_qp AS aqp, question_bank AS qb, complexity_type AS c "
                        + "WHERE assessment_id ='"+assessment_id+"' "
                        + "AND aqp.question_id = qb.question_id "
                        + "AND qb.complexity_type_id = c.complexity_type_id "
                        + "GROUP BY c.complexity_type_id";
                Statement st2a1 = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet1a1 = st2a1.executeQuery(sqla1);
                while (resultSet1a1.next()) {
            %>
            <tr>
                <td><%=resultSet1a1.getString("complexity_type_name")%></td>
                <td><%=resultSet1a1.getString("cnt")%></td>
                <td><input type='number' class='assmt_count' id='assmt_count' min="0" max="<%=resultSet1a1.getString("cnt")%>" name="cnt<%=resultSet1a1.getString("complexity_type_id")%>" disabled/></td>
            </tr>
            <%
                }
            %>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Total Questions</td>
                <td id='total_count'></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: $('body').on('#assmt_count', 'keyup', function() {
 alert("hi");
});

since your second page is dynamically added,

Comment: @akhil aravind still not working